# App freeze when is semaphore waiting for signal from operation block

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, afnetworking

Semaphore freeze my app when is waiting for signal

```
-(void) procceddQueue {


 dispatch_queue_t queue_qu = dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0);

 dispatch_semaphore_t sema_qu = dispatch_semaphore_create(0);

 dispatch_async(queue_qu, ^{

for (QueueItem *item in self.queueItems) {
    [[UploadService sharedInstance] buildPostRequestForItem:item :sema_qu];

}


    });

dispatch_semaphore_wait(sema_qu, DISPATCH_TIME_FOREVER);

[self updateQueue];
[self.queueItems removeAllObjects];
```

}

I proceed signal sema_qu variable to the operation block located in the other class. 
I am using AFNetworking and I am not sure is possible to implement semaphore with AFNetworking.

Comment: Are you signaling the semaphore in buildPostRequestForItem:: or at all? E.g. dispatch_semaphore_signal(sema_qu);

Comment: yes like this: dispatch_semaphore_signal(sema_qu);

Comment: Why are you signaling the semaphore in buildPostRequestForItem:: and not in proceedQueue? I don't have much experience with GCD, but I would assume that your app is freezing because you attempting to signal the semaphore on a different thread.

Comment: Try putting dispatch_semaphore_signal(sema_qu); after the for loop in proceedQueue.

Comment: That was my first solution but in that case semaphore is not waiting for signaling.

Comment: Do you mind including the method body of buildPostRequestForItem::?

Comment: @Jonathan thanks for the help I found solution using dispatch_group_t  instead semaphore.